# Finding the order of a given element in a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, cyclic-groups

Following on from my own example question in one of my previous posts I now want to better understand how to find the order of an element in a cyclic group G.

So in my previous example we had the group $G = \mathbb{Z}_{59}^{\times}$

I want to work out the order of 11 in group G. How would one compute and calculate this?

So far, I assume that you do 11^1 mod 59, 11^2 mod 59, 11^3 mod 59,..., 11^n mod 59 = 0?

Would be amazing to see how this would be computed and what other capabilities cyclic groups have

Comment: $59$ is prime, so every non-trivial element generates the group.

Comment: What is your group ? the addition modulo 59? or  the multiplication modulo 59 except zero ?

Comment: @lulu but then how do i compute the order of 11 in group G? Like i want to see steps of calculations to better understand this all

Comment: Well, perhaps I had the group wrong.  I thought you meant the cyclic group of order $59$.  What did you actually mean?

Comment: @ChinnapparajR apologies Sir it was meant to be multiplicative cyclic group so Z*

Comment: So the group has order $58$, which makes my first comment irrelevant (since $58$ is not prime).

Comment: but then how do i compute the order of 11 in group G? Like i want to see steps of calculations to better understand this all

Comment: There is no difficulty computing the powers of $11\pmod {59}$.  We note that $11^2=121\equiv 3 \pmod {59}$, for instance.  $11^4\equiv 33$ therefore, and so on.

Comment: i dont suppose you could kindly answer it in full please, so computing the order of 11 in  but then how do i compute the order of 11 in group $G = \mathbb{Z}_{59}^{\times}$

Comment: I'll post something below.

Comment: A related good exercise (on finite abelian groups, which are just slightly more general than finite cyclic groups): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3309443

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to compute the order of $11\pmod {59}$:

Note that $58=2\times 29$ so the possible orders are $1,2,29,58$.  Easy to see that $11^2\equiv 3 \pmod {59}$ so we just need to consider $11^{29}$.

To do that we remark that $$11^2\equiv 3\implies 11^4\equiv 9\implies 11^8\equiv 22$$

(all congruences $\pmod {59}$ of course).

Continuing we have $$11^{16}\equiv 22^2\equiv 12$$

And now we get $$11^{24}\equiv 11^{16}\times 11^8\equiv 12\times 22\equiv 28$$

And then $$11^{29}\equiv 11\times 11^4\times 11^{24}\equiv 11\times 9\times 28\equiv 58\equiv -1$$

Thus we have eliminated all the possible orders except $58$ so the order of $11\pmod {59}$ is $58$.

Note:  there's nothing unique about the preceding calculations. This path looked short to me, but there might well be others as good or better.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i am sorry but where did the 58 come from and how did you know the possible orders were 1,2,29,58?

Comment: The order of your group is $58$ (it is all the integers $\pmod {59}$ except for $0$).  The order of an element in any finite group divides the order of the group.

Comment: @Mike  Well, how do you eliminate $29$ as a possible order?  $4$ has order $29$ $\pmod {59}$, for instance.

Comment: So if i had group Z*67 then the order of group is 66? 67-1

Comment: Yes.  For any prime $p$ the multiplicative group $\pmod p$ has order $p-1$.

Comment: I see that makes sense, so once you do p-1 then you find all the multiples for p-1 which becomes the order? after that apply it to 11? i do not understand why you chose 29 as the exponent value

Comment: Well, the order must divide $p-1$, which is $58$ in this case.  Factoring that we see that the order must be one of $1,2,29,58$.  These are all the factors!  Of course, if you replace $59$ by a large prime, this can all be quite difficult.

Comment: @lulu Good Point, forgot to check that.

Comment: i understand @lulu but then why did you specifically do 11^29 as opposed to say 11^2 or 11^58?

Comment: Well, $11^2$ was easy, that's just $3$.  There's no point computing $11^{58}$...that's clearly $1$ (that would be true for any non-zero residue).  So that just leaves $29$.

Comment: If you are doing this in a spreadsheet, or in a program, you can just list all the powers of $11\pmod {59}$.  At each stage, all you are doing is multiplying by $11$ and reducing, so each step is easy...but of course there are a lot of steps.

Comment: no but then you calculated 11^2 etc. my question is why did you not multiple the result of 11^2 11^58 11^2 11^29 and then do the modulo of that result

Comment: No idea what you mean.  As I say, $11^{58}$ is clearly $1$, so why include it in your product?

Comment: As I said in the post, however, you could compute $11^{29}$ in multiple ways.  I just picked a path that looked good to me.  Try a different one!

Comment: I should say:  [Iterated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), which is what I did here, is a very standard method of modular computation.

Comment: @user23473433819233d Curiously here it is actually easier to use *baby-giant steps* - I added an answer showing that.

Comment: @lulu I think I get it now! :) So basically we compute all the possible powers, i.e. 1,2,29,58 and see which one gives one. Whichever one gives an output of -1 or 1 is the final answer right?

Comment: @BillDubuque I think I get it now! :) So basically we compute all the possible powers, i.e. 1,2,29,58 and see which one gives one. Whichever one gives an output of -1 or 1 is the final answer right?

Comment: Well...not the possible powers but the possible orders.   And we are looking for the least of the possible orders that gives $1$.

Comment: @lulu I get it now I think! So long as any one of the possible orders gives 1 then the power that gave 1 is the answer? I'm so very close to understanding the answer but I will upvote and accept your answer but please please please explain whether the final answer was 58 because it gave 1?

Comment: Not quite.  It's $58$ because it is the smallest power that gives $1$.  The "smallest" part is critical there.  Any integer $n$, prime to $59$, satisfies $n^{58}\equiv 1\pmod {59}$.

Answer (score 2):

To the general question: I don't think you're going to get an answer as simple as you want. For background, see [Wikipedia: Multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) .

For the complexity of a mature algorithm, see https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order and this previous answer: [Algorithms for finding the multiplicative order of an element in a group of integers mod m](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837489/algorithms-for-finding-the-multiplicative-order-of-an-element-in-a-group-of-inte)

Answer (score 1):

Worth note: [Shanks baby-giant step](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3133816/242)  works in a group knowing only an order *bound*,  e.g. $\!\!\bmod 59\!:$

$\qquad\,\ \begin{array}{c | c } r & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7  \\ \hline
11^{\large r}\! & 1 & 11 & 3 & 33 & 9 & \color{#0a0}{40} & 27 & \color{#c00}2 \end{array}\ $ via $\ 11^{\large\color{} 2}\equiv 3\,$ so $\!\!\begin{align}&\ \ 1\to \ \ 3\to\   9\, \ldots\\ &\ \ \ \ \ \ 11\to 33\to 99\!\equiv\! \color{#0a0}{40}\,\ldots\end{align}$

$\qquad\ \ \, \begin{array}{c | c } q &  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
\color{#c00}2^{\large q}  & 2 & 4 & 8 & 16 & 32 & 5 & 10 & 20 & \color{#0a0}{40} \end{array}\ $ as above,  all *trivial* modular writhmetic.

Hence $\, 11^{\large 5} \equiv \color{#0a0}{40}\equiv 2^{\large 9}\equiv (11^{\large 7})^{\large 9}\,\Rightarrow\, \bbox[6px,border:1px solid #c00]{1\equiv 11^{\large 63-5}\equiv 11^{\large 58}}$

and $58$ is the *least*, else for smaller $\,7q\!-\!r\!:\ 11^{\large 7q-r}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 2^{\large q}\equiv 11^{\large r}$ contra table values.

This may be faster than the other methods since here *all* arithmetic is trivial $ $  [$2\cdot n\,$ or $\,3\cdot n$].

But generally this method will be less efficient than using divisibility constraints and/or  deeper ideas (e.g. the [Order Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1188614/242) implicitly used in lulu's answer or,  by Euler's criterion $\,11^{\large 29}\!\equiv (11\,|\,58)\equiv -1\,$ by a quick Legendre symbol computation). However, the baby-giant step method is well-worth knowing since it proves useful in various contexts.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/208293/242) for general algorithms for order computation (some of which use this and related ideas).